# How to calculate connection pool as per threads in tomcat to avoid ORA-12519

Tags: spring, performance, tomcat7, connection-pooling, jdbctemplate

**Issue :** I am getting below error

#### ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

#### Desc:

I want to configure threads and connection pool in tomcat to use them at optimum level.
can i configure highly throughput  up-to 500-600 threads, 
I have few more servlets which will use the database with similar threads.

I am calling a servlet to insert entry in db (code mentioned below) with 150 Threads with tasks to complete are 100000

```
    static int joblimit = 100000;
    static int TPS = 150;

     public static void insertMethod()
{

    RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(TPS);
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < joblimit; i++) {
        rateLimiter.acquire(); // may wait
        final int j = i;
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                log.info(str);
                try {
                    callInsertURL(j);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error(e);
                }
                if (index == joblimit) {
                    long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
                    String oneThreadProcessedInSecs = ""+(float)(1*(timeTaken/60)/joblimit);
                    log.info(joblimit + " jobs completed in "
                            + timeTaken 
                            + " msec i.e ["+(float)(timeTaken/60)+"sec,"+"] with " + TPS + " tps, oneThreadProcessedInSecs="+oneThreadProcessedInSecs);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    try {
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        log.info("--------------All Tasks Processed Processed----------------------------");
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**My Tomcat and Java configurations :**
**Context.xml entry**

`<Resource name="jdbc/myoracle" 
              global="jdbc/myoracle"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myip:1521:mydb"
              username="myusername" password="mypassword" maxActive="250" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
              />`

**server.xml entry**

`<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />`

**Springconfiguration: servlet-context.xml**

`<beans:bean id="dbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/myoracle"/>
</beans:bean>`

**ServeltController will be calling below method to insert into DB:**

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("commonDAO")
protected CommonDAO commonDAO;

String qry = "INSERT INTO TB_CUSTOMER(customer_msisdn,op_id,cuser,country_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
String[] colNamesTobeReturned = {"CUSTOMER_ID"};
commonDAO.insertOrUpdateWithReturnPK(qry, colNamesTobeReturned, msisdn,opid,cuser,countryid);
```

**Method which will access DB:**

```
    public Long insertOrUpdateWithReturnPK(final String qry,final String[] colNamesTobeReturned,final Object... params)
        {
            KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
            try {
                getJdbcTemplate().update(
                        new PreparedStatementCreator() {
                            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(qry, colNamesTobeReturned);
                                utilMapParamsToPStmt(ps,params);
                                return ps;
                            }
                        },
                        keyHolder);
                if(keyHolder != null)
                    return keyHolder.getKey().longValue();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                handleDBExceptions(e);
            }
                return 0L;
        }
```

Comment: Your DB method can be improved, as you don't want to construct a `JdbcTEmplate` each time you need one. It is a very heavy object to construct, you want to create it once and reuse it. And you shouldn't pass along the `DataSource`. For calculating pool size [this](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing) is an interesting read, basically don't make it that high.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thank you for the reply,
I would want to create only object once like datasource, 
I have controller class like below, from there i pass datasource, you want me to create JdbcTemplate also like this ?
Can i use the same object for other controllers also?



`@Controller
     public class CntCustomer extends BaseController{}

     public class BaseController {

 @Autowired
 @Qualifier(CommonDAOConstants.JNDI_NAME)
 protected DataSource dataSource;

 public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
  this.dataSource = dataSource;
 }
 }`

Comment: Don't add code in comments add it to your question. Yuor controllers, daos' etc. should be singletons (they shouldn't keep state), you also want to construct the `JdbcTemplate` just once, after construction it is thread safe and as mentioned it is a heavy object to construct as it does a lookup to the database to determine type etc. It doesn't make sense to inject a `DataSource` in your controller, that is a web thing and shouldn't know anything about it.

Comment: @M.Deinum, sure , I will modify the question accordingly.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have change the code still with 60 threads also i am getting the same error.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073434/spring-connection-pooling-issue. So as stated earlier make `JdbcTemplate` a singleton and I wouldn't use that high level of db connections (if you have read the link I gave earlier you should be able to make some calculations).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68648/discussion-between-azhar-and-m-deinum).